# How to search for the maximum value in a multidimensional array in a given range

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional `$array` that has a lot of various values. I am trying to get the maximum value in a given range in this case lets say the maximum value within x1,y0 and x2,y7, thus the result would be `6` using the data below.

It seems like a common problem for searching within coordinates in multidimensional array... but I cant find a simple solution and everything that I try to do seems to be rather extensive in the coding. I was wondering if there is a function that would allow me to search in this array using my criteria in an efficient way.

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 10;
$array[0][3] = 3;
$array[1[0] = 1;
$array[1][1] = 1;
$array[2][5] = 6;
```

Comment: Do you need only maximum value, or also coordinates of that value? How big are your multidimensional arrays, and how frequent you need to locate these values? Would simple O(N) solution be enough, or you need log time or even O(1) ?

Comment: Try [two-dimensional RMQ](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~stelo/cpm/cpm07/2D_range_queries_amir.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 10;
$array[0][3] = 3;
$array[1][0] = 1;
$array[1][1] = 1;
$array[2][5] = 6;

$max = false;
$x1 = 1; $x2 = 2;
$y1 = 0; $y2 = 7;

foreach($array as $x => $y_vals) {    
    if($x < $x1 || $x > $x2)
        continue;

    foreach($y_vals as $y => $val) {
        if($y < $y1 || $y > $y2)
            continue;

        if(false === $max || $max < $val)
            $max = $val;
    }
}

print $max; //6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = null;
for ($x = $startx; $x <= $endx; $x++) {
    for ($y = $starty; $y <= $endy; $y++) {
        if (isset($array[$x][$y]) && ($max === null || $array[$x][$y] > $max)) {
            $max = $array[$x][$y];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 10;
$array[0][3] = 3;
$array[1][0] = 1;
$array[1][1] = 1;
$array[2][5] = 6;

$vals = array();
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
         ) as $value) {
    $vals[] = $value;
}
$max = max($vals);
echo $max;
```